# Syntax: typedef and struct tag explanation

Tags: c, syntax

In following example:

```
typedef struct Books {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int book_id;
} Book;
```

The `Book` can be used then, to declare variable, like:

```
Book myBook;
```

But what the meaning of `Books`? How it can be used, or why we need it?
I interested mostly in plain C, but if you can explain about C++ as well it will be great.

--edited--

To be more specific, what the difference between code above and following code:

```
typedef struct {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int book_id;
} Book;
```

Why we ever need an extra literal in first example?

Found good explanation here:
[Tag vs. Type Names in C and C++](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names)

Comment: Thanks, dbush. I also saw the identical code, but without `Books` literal. What is the difference?

Comment: What don't you understand from any C book's explanation? What is your **specific** problem? There are many tutorials and C books to be found.

Comment: Olaf, i tryed to find information, but in tutorials all the explanation is around `Book` alias, but noting is said about `Books`, regarding to this example.

Comment: You thing the letter `s` in the name makes a difference?? That is ridiculous! Next time you ask the same question about `Car` vs. `Cars`? No, offence, but you really should get a C book and start reading from the very first page.

Comment: Olaf, may be i dissapoint you, using `Book` and `Books` literals, but if you look at example provided, you will see, that they used in different locations in source code. The question was about "top" location.

Comment: And that you did not find in a good C book? (whatever your mean with "top location") And C and C++ are **different** languages! Sorry to say, but you did not do any effort to answer this yourself before asking. Btw. that linked site starts with nonsense already - at least in C. The rest is not better. It mystifies something which is very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` says that `Book` is an alias for `struct Books`.  Anywhere you use one, you can use the other.

The only exception is if `struct Books` contains a pointer to another `struct Books`.  In that case, you can't use the alias.

EDIT:

You can do the above if you use a forward declaration:

```
typedef struct Books Book;

struct Books {
   Book *moreBooks;
}
```

As for `Books`, that by itself is not a valid type.  You need to prefix it with the `struct` keyword.  This differs from C++ where the `struct` (or `class`) keyword is optional when referencing it.

EDIT 2:

In the second code sample you give, `Book` is an alias for an anonymous struct.  In that case, the alias must be used to reference it.

Comment: You can still use the alias in that situation (by using slightly different syntax)